# Why inductor voltage at $t=0$ is equal to source voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

I am sorry to ask this elementary, fundamental  and most repeatedly asked but i have some doubts that were not cleared during my undergrad days. I will try to present my doubts in following points.
1 At t=0 , there is no current so no magnetic field inside inductor but there is a voltage equals in magnitude to that of source. 
* Where does this voltage comes from, many people say that it is due to fact that inductor oppose to change in current but my question is what is the phenomena which leads the inductor to develop voltage (equals to source voltage) to oppose current.

** How the voltage is equal to source voltage even in the presence of intrinsic(wire resistance) or external resistance. ( why it is not Vs-Vr)

*** Then what leads the current to flow just after t=0 say at t=0.00000..1 sec as source voltage and load(inductor voltages are equal).

Comment: The answers to your questions depend on the circuit you are looking at. Please share the schematic of the circuit you want to ask about.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage does not just appear on inductor by itself; one has to connect the inductor to a source of voltage, or induce voltage on it by changing magnetic field, in which case the inductor charges are the source of the voltage.

Voltage is difference of Coulomb potential. This difference depends on presence of the Coulomb field, and this in turn depends on positions of all electric charges, but mostly those near the point of space where the potential is studied. So any voltage between two points is due to presence of electric charges that are arranged in such a way that they produce non-negligible Coulomb field in the space between the two points.

If the voltage between two points of the inductor is due to battery, then it is the charges in and on the surface of the battery which create most of the Coulomb field near the battery and inductor, and that is why there is potential variation and voltage on the terminals of the inductor. The inductor itself produces Coulomb field too as soon as it is under influence of the battery, but the field responsible for the voltage is that of the battery (as long as the battery maintains its usual voltage, voltage due to inductor's field is negligible).

If the voltage is due to changing magnetic field, things are a little different. The coil is not connected to anything, there is no closed circuit, but there is voltage between its terminals. Why? Changing magnetic field of some external source (e.g. moving magnet) is associated with induced electric field (of the same source). This is a solenoidal (circulating) field, it does not contribute to voltage. However, this external induced field together with the inductor's induced electric field induce electric current inside but also shift of mobile electric charges in the inductor surface so that net Coulomb field of the surface charges almost cancels the total induced electric field inside the conducting wires of the inductor. This Coulomb field of the shifted surface charges is the reason for voltage appearing on the coil. If the magnetic field changes rapidly enough or there is a lot of coils in the inductor (and lots of surface charges shifted), the concentration of the charges on the inductor terminals or coils can get high enough for sparks to occur.

Answer (score 1):

> How the voltage is equal to source voltage even in the presence of
>   intrinsic(wire resistance) or external resistance. ( why it is not
>   Vs-Vr)

Let's consider a series circuit consisting of a battery of voltage $V$, resistance $R$, an inductor $L$ and a switch initially in the open position. The resistance can be the wire resistance, or any other total resistance in the  circuit. At time t=0 the switch is closed. Per Kirchhoff's voltage law we have

$$+V-i_{L}(t)R-V_{L}(t)=0$$

Per Faradays law we have:

$$V_{L}(t)=L\frac{di_{L}(t)}{dt}$$

So our first equation becomes

$$+V-i_{L}(t)R-L\frac{di_{L}(t)}{dt}=0$$

In order to find $i_{L}(t)$ as a function of time, and therefore $V_{L}(t)$ as a function of time, we need the solution to this differential equation. The solution, considering zero initial current in the inductor, is

$$i_{L}(t)=\frac{V}{R}(1-e^{-Rt/L})$$

Note for time t=0, $i_{L}(t)=0$. This says you can't change the current in an ideal inductor instantaneously (i.e., in zero time). So according to the first equation the voltage across the resistor is zero and $V_{L}(t)=V$, that is, all the voltage is across the inductor.

For t=∞ , we have $i_{L}(t)=V/R$. The current is now constant and a maximum. The current is at its maximum and the voltage across the inductor is zero. An ideal inductor looks like a short circuit when current is constant. This also comes directly from the Faradays law (the second equation) since for $\frac{di_{L}(t)}{dt}=0$, we have $V_{L}(t)=0$. For time between t=0 and t=∞, just plug the time into the equation.

> Then what leads the current to flow just after t=0 say at t=0.00000..1
>   sec as source voltage and load(inductor voltages are equal).

Although an inductor *resists* a change in current, it doesn't *prevent* current from changing. From the last equation current starts at zero and ends at a maximum of $V/R$. From the first equation the inductor voltage starts at $V_{L}=V$ and ends at $V_{L}=0$.

Hope this helps.